# Python: Creating tuple from one column based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a dataset like below:

```
dfTrip:
user_id     status    length
1335         start      0  -> 1st trip starts here
1335         zz         1
1335         zz         7
1335         zz         1
1335         end        5  -> 14 in total for 1st trip
1335         zz         1  -> not added
1335         start      0  -> 2nd trip starts here
1335         zz         4
1335         zz         7
1335         zz         6
1335         end        5  -> 22 in total for 2nd trip
```

I want to calculate the sum of trip length for each "user_id" and save in a dictionary. The trip should start from "start" and end on "end". For example, here we should have this result:

```
myDict={(1: 14), (2: 22),...}
```

the keys show the ith trip and the values show the length of the trip.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is this using pandas?

Comment: "sum"? Really? Instead of something useful like "pandas" or "dataframe"?

Comment: What is that stray row in between the "end" and the "start" for? Is it to be ignored?

Comment: Yes, it should be ignored. @mhawke

Comment: Yes, it is using pandas. @Tai

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. Do you know the answer? @Tai

Comment: @Mahsa I do not and I hope other people do :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more clever solution but this should work. We need to iterate through the rows.

```
trips = {} #Initialize dict
onTrip = False 
i = 1
for index, row in dfTrip.iterrows():

    if row['status']=='start': #Start the trip
        onTrip=True
        trips[i]=row['length']
        continue

    if onTrip: #Add each value of the trip
        trips[i]+=row['length']

    if row['status']=='end': #End the trip, incrementing i
        onTrip=False
        i+=1
```

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that if you are wanting to do this for each user_id, you will probably need to wrap it in another sort of for-loop so you can make a dictionary for each user